# operator<< called only in Linux

Tags: c++, cross-platform, cross-compiling, easylogging++

I'm using [easyloggingpp](https://github.com/muflihun/easyloggingpp) in a "big" cross platform project. Big enough that I can't create a simple running example that reproduce the behavior I'm about to describe.

So I have some `enum` type define in some header, let say:

In `types.h`:

```
typedef enum MyEnum
{
    First,
    Second
} MyEnum;
```

> The enum is a `C` enum since the project is ABI safe and the API is a thin layer of C functions and types (Our implementation for the Hour Glass pattern)

and it also has 2 functions to handle printing, assume that these are the functions (in reality only the functions' bodies are different):

```
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, MyEnum value) 
{ 
    return out << get_string(value);
}
```

In `types.cpp`, I have:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    const char* get_string(MyEnum value)
    {
        assert(0);
    }
}
```

If I call something like this in my code

```
MyEnum x = First;
std::stringstream os;
os << "Value of x is: " << x;
```

The `assert(0)` I have in the `get_string()` function will be triggered.

But if I call the logger:

```
LOG_INFO("Value of x is: " << x);
```

For some reason, In Visual Studio (2017 if that matters), when the logger's inner stream member (which is also of type `std::stringstream`) is called with `x` it calls the `<ostream>` function: `_Myt& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL operator<<(int _Val)` , i.e. it treats the enum to an integer, and prints the value as a number instead of using my operator overload.

But, in Linux - the same code, compiled with `gcc 5.4.0`, calls my `operator<<` and does trigger the assertion.

I'm not really sure where to start in order to understand this...

So the real question is - what could cause such a difference between compilers\OSs? and where do I start with debugging it? or if someone knows what is causing this, I'd love to know.

EDIT:

`LOG_INFO` is a macro of the logging infrastructure which eventually calls:
`m_logger->stream() << msg;` where `m_logger->stream()` returns `std::stringstream&` and `msg` is a templated value parameter which in my example is the instance of `x`

Comment: @Ron "so the real question is - what could cause such a difference between compilers\OSs? and where do I start with debugging it?"

Comment: What you have is an [unscoped enumeration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Unscoped_enumeration). Those are basically named integer constants. Perhaps what you need is [*scoped* enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations)?

Comment: On an unrelated note, in C++ you don't need the `typedef`, the enumeration tag name is also a type-name.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit (get_string() is under a namespace).
The enum is a `C` enum since the project is ABI safe and the API is a thin layer of `C` functions and types (Our implementation for the Hour Glass pattern)

Comment: Maybe that's part of the problem? Try `typedef enum MyEnum {...} MyEnumType` and see if that changes anything.